# How can I win more headers during a corner?

Tags: fifa-16

In previous versions of FIFA, I didn't concede many goals from corners but didn't score too many goals either when playing online.

I would defend the corners by holding the shoot button as the ball came into the box.  Relying on the game to automatically switch me to the nearest player to the ball I would almost always win the header.

When it came to scoring from a header, I seemed to have a fair chance of winning the header by using the above tactics.  A small proportion of the won headers would be goals.

In FIFA 16, I seem to be struggling to both defend and win any header in the opponent's box.

When it comes to defending, I seem to lose somewhere between 30-50% of the headers using the same method.

When it comes to attacking, I don't seem to have any chance unless I use a near post run AND call a 2nd player to the ball (I cross as soon as the 2nd player runs towards me).  This gives me a better chance of having 1 or 2 unmarked players at the near post, although the angle is a lot harder to score from.

Could someone provide an insight into the problems with my method?

Is there a better method to scoring from a corner?

Comment: Are you talking specifically about winning headers from a corner or about any other methods of scoring from the set piece?

Comment: Corners specifically.  Set pieces I don't really have the same problems.

Comment: Are you using the button to adjust your position? I think it's LT for Xbox & L2 for Playstation.

I have always sound success using this method, especially when playing online, as the CPU AI is generally quite good at countering this tactic and will perform the same move against you.

Answer (score 1):

I usually win (85%) of the headers in the opponents box. I always assign a player with a high cross rating, regardless of preferred foot, although left footed players crossing from the left corner does work quite well and vice-versa.

Anyway, when awarded a corner, **don't** adjust the position. Always leave the direction as default. Then press and hold your cross button (O for Xbox, Square for PS) and power up to 3-4 bars on the meter at the bottom of the screen.

This has a high chance of the ball being played directly into the box. Depending on your difficulty, the 'keeper will not contest the ball, relying on his defenders, although, for me, the lower the difficulty, the higher the chance the 'keeper comes out to claim it. The players that receives the cross depends on your set-up. Usually, a defender will be there (for added height). The attacking midfielder. And strikers lurk around. On my set-up, which is a 3-2-3-2, the right-most defender is in the box, regardless of height, the attackers alternate between the far post and just outside the box, and my attacking midfielder is always there.

When the ball is played, just press the shoot button to the desired power level, aim with the direction stick and the goal will be scored. As you can see, I don't always get it. And of that 85%, about 90% of that is goals scored. The others are misses or saves.

To defend, when the ball is played into your box, always keep close to your mark. The game switches defenders for you, which is dumb, as sometimes I get my striker trying to mark their striker. Anyway, keep close and only power up the shoot bar, not passing. This will either knock the ball out of bounds again, or up the field. The A.I. usually goes for into the area, not always the box. Try to stay as close to your mark as possible, as the ball might go behind or in front of you otherwise.

Other than that, most times it is also down to luck. But with constant practice and using your best to cross the ball in, this is always a chance to score that goal.